# Web API cannot bind Immutable object with GET but can with POST

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to bind Immutable model with GET method. Its works fine with POST. Why ?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get([FromQuery]Something something)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]Something something)
    {
    }



    public class Something
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; }
        public int Prop2 { get;  }

        public Something(string prop1, int prop2)
        {
            Prop1 = prop1;
            Prop2 = prop2;
        }
    }
```

With GET method I get the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type
>   WebApplication2.Something;. Model bound complex types must not be
>   abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

Does it have something to do with the `[FromQuery]` and `[FromBody]`attributes ?

Comment: `and must have a parameterless constructor.` ==>  `public Something(string prop1, int prop2)`

Comment: But in POST it works and it uses same deserializer. If I have parametless constructor my props need to have setters to set properties and then they will not be immutable.

Comment: Why do you want an immutable model?  I don't see the point.

Comment: For example if You have complex pipeline in application and You don't wan't to somebody change this object. Its just good practice to have immutable objects.

Comment: @Eser you really think that make public constructor change something? Properties will be not filled..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[FromBody]` attribute flags to MVC pipeline to use the configured formatters to bind data from the request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the request.

The `JsonInputFormatter` is the default formatter, based on Json.NET and it simply does a JSON string body deserialization ([code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L303)):

```
 model = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, type);
```

Cause during deserialization the constructor of object is not called, you don't have any errors like "*must have a parameterless constructor*".

---

In contrary, for `[FromQuery]Something` the [ComplexTypeModelBinder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs) is used and it first creates an instance of your `Something` class  by calling default constructor and then assign corresponding values to public properties. Check [BindModelCoreAsync method for implementation details](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs#L85).

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get([FromQuery]Something something)
{
    return "value";
}
```

The `[FromQuery]Something something` parameter expects you to send in an object of that type. You can't do this in the querystring, as it can only take in "simple types" like `int` and `string`

Comment: The model binder **will** map querystring parameters to the Type's properties. You appear to suggest an answer that you say won't work. I'm confused.